# How to only include the class specified and not the subclasses within in Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

The list 'c' that I want should just have the name of the ratios, like c = [Standard Deviation, Sharpe Ratio, Treynor's Ratio]. With the current code it is taking in additional information (things within **'h3'**). Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36"}
    
url = https://www.moneycontrol.com/mutual-funds/nav/axis-bluechip-fund-growth/MAA009
response12 = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
bs12 = BeautifulSoup(response12)
pos = bs12.find_all('h3', attrs = {'class' : 'list TAC'})
c = []
for div in pos:
  c.append(div.text.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `contents`

> contents is an ordered list of the Tag and NavigableString objects
> contained within a page element.

```
for div in pos:
  c.append(div.contents[0])

print(c)
```

results

```
['Standard Deviation', 'Beta', 'Sharpe Ratio', "Treynor's Ratio", "Jension's Alpha"]
```